# Is there a way to force vim youcompleteme plugin to do semantic analysis again?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

Is there some shortcut to force ycm to re-run semantic analysis on the code. Eg. I get some error, I correct it and I want to check, but ycm on my machine refreshes only after about 5 secs. One way is to `:w<Cr> :e<CR>` but it saves the edits which I might not want. Is there some key binding to just refresh the semantic analysis result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `:YcmForceCompileAndDiagnostics`?

> Calling this command will force YCM to immediately recompile your file and display any new diagnostics it encounters. Do note that recompilation with this command may take a while and during this time the Vim GUI will be blocked.

```
nnoremap <F5> :YcmForceCompileAndDiagnostics<CR>
```